# Office deployment tool not working as it should

Tags: windows, automation, office365

I'm quite often making new computers "ready" and they have Office 365 installed in multiple languages.
I'm trying to remove them all at the same time using the office deployment tool.
Below is the config I'm using. It's probably a bit "butchered" as I just tried a lot of code at the end.
It's Office 365 nb-no and Onenote nb-no that doesn't get removed automatically, the other versions gets removed.

Heres the config I'm using:

```
<Configuration>

<Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="Current">
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
    <Language ID="MatchInstalled" />
    <Language ID="MatchPreviousMSI" />
    <Language ID="en-us" />
      <Language ID="nb-no" />
      <Language ID="da-dk" />
      <Language ID="en-gb" />
      <Language ID="fi-fi" />
      <Language ID="sv-se" />
    </Product>
    <Product ID="OneNoteFreeRetail">
      <Language ID="MatchInstalled" />
      <Language ID="MatchPreviousMSI" />
      <Language ID="nb-no" />
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
</Add>
    <RemoveMSI />
    <Remove All="TRUE">
    </Remove>
  <!--  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" Channel="Current" /> -->

  <!--  <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />  -->

  <!--  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />  -->

</Configuration>
```